# SQL Select first price when grouping by customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQL so apologies in advance if I'm missing the obvious.

My data consists of customer contract number, service date, and a list of prices. I need to be able to group by customer, pull the first price by service date and in another column have the sum of all prices.

So I have something like:

```
SELECT
CONTRACT, 
SUM(PRICES) as [TOTAL SPENT]
FIRST(PRICE) as [FIRST PRICE]
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CONTRACT
ORDER BY CONTRACT
```

But apparently First is not a built in function name (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server). Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to provide the sql to create the necessary table/s fields?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: You said "pull the first price by service date"...but the service date is not retrieve in the select...so which price is the "first" one? Sample data and desired output would be nice to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    -- @tmp represents your table
    declare @tmp table (
     [Contract] int,
     [Prices] decimal(18,5),
     [ServiceDate] datetime
    )

    -- some testing data - you may skip that
    insert into @tmp values(1, 100, '2011-01-01')
    insert into @tmp values(1, 200, '2011-01-02')
    insert into @tmp values(2, 10, '2011-01-01')
    insert into @tmp values(2, 20, '2011-01-02')
    insert into @tmp values(2, 30, '2011-01-03')


    SELECT
      [CONTRACT], 
      SUM(PRICES) as [TOTAL SPENT],
      (SELECT TOP 1 t2.PRICES FROM @tmp t2 
       WHERE t2.[Contract] = t1.[Contract] 
       ORDER BY [SERVICEDATE]) as [FIRST PRICE]
    FROM @tmp t1
    GROUP BY [CONTRACT]
    ORDER BY [CONTRACT]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CONTRACT, 
           SUM(PRICES) OVER(PARTITION BY CONTRACT) as [TOTAL SPENT],
           PRICE as [FIRST PRICE],
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Contract Order By  ServiceDate) 
    FROM TABLE
)
SELECT CONTRACT, [TOTAL SPENT], [FIRST PRICE]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY CONTRACT
```

This picks the first row  from each Contract-group according to the `ServiceDate`. This approach has the advantage you can select all columns without needing to use an aggregate function or to include it into the `GROUP BY`. Note that you need at least SQLServer 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    CONTRACT, 
    SUM(PRICE) as [TOTAL SPENT],
    (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE FROM [TABLE]
     WHERE CONTRACT_DATE = MIN(T.CONTRACT_DATE)
     AND   CONTRACT = T.CONTRACT) AS [FIRST PRICE]
    FROM [TABLE] T
    GROUP BY CONTRACT
    ORDER BY CONTRACT
```

See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8229/2).

Comment: What if there are duplicates? The correlated subquery needs a TOP 1 at least - though I don't think this is going to be the most efficient approach in any case.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good spot, I actually thought about the `TOP 1` while I was writing the but forgot to add it in - answer now edited. As for efficiency this is unlikely be a problem in practice unless there's mounds of data (and using `MIN` in the subselect is certainly a lot more efficient than `ORDER BY` as suggested in another post).

Comment: Well, it really depends. If there is an index to support it, generating a row_number using that order by is going to be a lot more efficient in a lot of cases than scanning for the MIN for every row.